# Build Angular 5 package with external js librairies

Tags: angular, npm, wrapper

I've created a wrapper for a JS libraire and I would like to share it through npm.

So, to do that I use SystemJS and scriptloader to load the js lib. 
It works fine and I can build my solution in prod mode.

But if I try to create an Angular package with ***angular-package-builder*** I got this error :

```
   [TypeScript] ngx-pivot-table/ngx-pivot-table.component.ts(22,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'System'.
   [TypeScript] ngx-pivot-table/ngx-pivot-table.component.ts(23,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'System'.
   [TypeScript] ngx-pivot-table/ngx-pivot-table.component.ts(25,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'System'.
```

Here is my component's code :

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    System.import('script-loader!./pivot.min.js').then(() => {
      this.render();
    }); 
  }
```

Here is my typing.d.ts file :

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var System: SystemJS;

interface SystemJS {
  import: (path?: string) => Promise<any>;
}enter code here

declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the content of the typings.d.ts to the top of the components code.

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks a lot :)